# Navigating to VF page with e.force:navigateToURL shows as classic

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am navigating to a visualforce page from a lightning component using: `$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL)` but when the user gets to the vf page it is styled as classic, even `lightningStyleSheets="true"`. How can I get the vf page to render as lightning ?

```
let url = response.getReturnValue();
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                urlEvent.setParams({
                    "url": url,
                    'isredirect' : "true"
                });
                urlEvent.fire();
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `url` ?

Comment: depends on some logic, but could be something like:  'apex/vfpage?id=xxx'

Comment: What is the domain and subdomain of the source page vs the actual domain and subdomain of the target page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong VF page, the one I saw actually didn't have lightningstylesheets=true. I gave it that attribute and it showed as lightning. My Mistake! Thanks though, I couldn't delete the question.

Answer (score -2):

> When using lightningStylesheets on a Visualforce page in Lightning Experience, the page can be displayed with Classic styling for some users. This behavior is normal and can be adjusted using the steps below.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000270470&language=en_US&type=1

After that, please use this statement in your helper to redirect back to VF page:

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "/apex/MYVF_page",
          "isredirect": "true"
        });
```

Comment: I've tidied up this answer and removed the other one. I'll just reiterate my encouragement to read [answer]. Thanks!